# python syntax for terminating a program when the user enters quit

Tags: python, syntax

Im trying to write a program that assigns an empty str to the variable myvar. then in a while loop the program asks for the user to type text, anything they want and it will print to the screen until the user enters the text quit which will end the loop and stop the program.

this is what I have

```
myvar = str("")
    while myvar != "quit":
    user_input = raw_input()
    user_input = myvar
print myvar
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you've got some syntax errors there; once you get the indentation right, you can just change line 4 from `user_input = myvar` to `myvar = user_input`.  Also, this seems like a homework question, which really isn't what StackOverflow is for at all.

Comment: Its from a practice problem set where I make a flowchart for it. but I dont need to write the code, i'm just doing this for the extra practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're pretty close, but the indentation's off and the logic needs a slight tweak:

```
myvar = ""
while myvar != "quit":
    myvar = raw_input()
    print myvar
```

note that this will also print `"quit"`.  I'll leave that as a final exercise to you to figure out how to cut that out.

Comment: Thanks. I see what I was doing wrong. The quit thing is something ill look into. Give me a few and ill post back with an answer.

Comment: +1 for giving an answer based on OP's code... that should help him learn and get better at coding

Comment: are you being sarcastic or serious?

Comment: serious ... entirely ... im rarely sarcastic on SO, and genuinely like to see people learn from the answers

Comment: for the program to not  print "quit" dont you use the sysexit()

Comment: ok, so I think im on the right path. This is what I got, after the while myvar.lower... can I put an if clause within the while loop which states "if myvar.lower() == "quit":" but after that I dont know know what to do. Can you give me a reference to read?

Comment: I think you want `if my_var.lower() == "quit": break` ... that will exit the for loop ... I dont know did you learn anything from it? I would hope so ... if not and your just gonna cut and paste ... mine is more fun :P

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
for output in iter(raw_input,"quit"):
    print output
```

Comment: Gotta love `iter` with a sentinel.  Although, you don't need the `lambda` ;-)  (`lambda :foo()` is pretty much the same thing as `foo`)

Comment: stupid me ... usually im casting to an int or something :P (or at least providing a prompt)